# How do I assign another owner for my Azure Tenant?

Tags: azure

Our company has recently purchased a new Azure tenant of which I am the owner.
I need to assign a secondary owner. Is this possible? if so how do I do it?

thanks in advance.

I have looked in the Microsoft learn website but not found anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following to assign another owner to your tenant .

***Go to Access control (IAM) in you subscription dashboard.***

[image]
Click on `+Add` to do the role assignment.

***Check for owner role in `Privileged adminstrator roles` to add another user as owner.***

> **Note:** One must have owner or user administrator role to assign roles.

[image]

***Select the user or member to which theowner role is to be assigned.***

[image]

***And check if the owner role is assigned in Access control (IAM )>azure role asignments.***

[image]